# Mass add to parent and child

Tags: php, wordpress

looking for a way to display only specific scripts on a parent page and all of its child pages. I'm trying to accomplish this without having to go in and add every single parent/child url.

Here's what I had:

````
 function answerConnect_add_script_wp_footer() {
  /** Tells what pg to display on AND it's child pgs **/
  if (is_page ( array('foley-al','fargo-nd','advantages','project-gallery','cabinet-redooring') ) ) {
     ?>
        <script>
             console.log("I'm an inline script tag added to the footer.");
  ( function( a , b , c , d , e , f , g ) { c[d] = c[d] || function() { (c[d].q = c[d].q || []).push(arguments); }; c[ '_lsAlias' ] = c[ d ]; e = a.createElement(b); e.type = 'text/javascript'; e.async = true; e.src = 'https://app.chatsupport.co/api/client/get/script/LS-1f4db298'; f = function() { g = a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0]; g.parentNode.insertBefore( e , g ); }; c.addEventListener( 'load' , f ); } )( document , 'script' , window , '_ls' ); _ls( 'init' , { 'projectId' : 'LS-1f4db298' } );
        </script>
     <?php
  }
 }```

I was later told this was wrong and should be:

```add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, function() {
      if ( is_page() && in_array( $ //pageidofparent, get_post_ancestors( get_the_id()))) {
               ?>
        <script>
             console.log("I'm in your footer.");
  ( function( a , b , c , d , e , f , g ) { c[d] = c[d] || function() { (c[d].q = c[d].q || []).push(arguments); }; c[ '_lsAlias' ] = c[ d ]; e = a.createElement(b); e.type = 'text/javascript'; e.async = true; e.src = 'https://app.chatsupport.co/api/client/get/script/LS-1f4db298'; f = function() { g = a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0]; g.parentNode.insertBefore( e , g ); }; c.addEventListener( 'load' , f ); } )( document , 'script' , window , '_ls' ); _ls( 'init' , { 'projectId' : 'LS-1f4db298' } );
        </script>
     <?php

    }

});
````

I'm still new to this so not sure how to use that last bit at all.

Comment: This article https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-a-list-of-child-pages-for-a-parent-page-in-wordpress/ might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As your needs, add this code to your `wp-content/your-theme/functions.php`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_footer_scripts' );
function my_footer_scripts(){
   if (is_tree(2)) { // Your parent page ID
   ?>
   <script>
       console.log("I'm an inline script tag added to the footer.");
       ( function( a , b , c , d , e , f , g ) { c[d] = c[d] || function() { (c[d].q = c[d].q || []).push(arguments); }; c[ '_lsAlias' ] = c[ d ]; e = a.createElement(b); e.type = 'text/javascript'; e.async = true; e.src = 'https://app.chatsupport.co/api/client/get/script/LS-1f4db298'; f = function() { g = a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0]; g.parentNode.insertBefore( e , g ); }; c.addEventListener( 'load' , f ); } )( document , 'script' , window , '_ls' ); _ls( 'init' , { 'projectId' : 'LS-1f4db298' } );
   </script>
  <?PHP
   }
}

function is_tree($pid) {      // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post;         // load details about this page
    if(is_page()&&($post->post_parent==$pid||is_page($pid))) 
        return true;   // we're at the page or at a sub page
    else 
        return false;  // we're elsewhere
};
```

#### Explanation

1. The code uses [WordPress action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) `wp_footer` to add our custom code to the footer
2. `is_tree()` is a custom function to check a specific page and it's childs by page ID